# How to use >C++11 with a ignition or gazebo project

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If I am compiling against `ign-*`, or `gazebo`, I get `-std=c++11` added to my CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. Now, I understand that ign-* and gazebo require C++11, but I want to use C++14 or C++17.

For example, `target_link_library(target ${IGNITION-TRANSPORT-LIBRARIES)` will add `-std=c++11` to the very end of my compile flags rendering any attempts like `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1z` useless.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17452/how-to-use-%3Ec++11-with-a-ignition-or-gazebo-project/) by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 768 on 2017-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What about if you use `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` at the top of your `CMakeLists,txt`?

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1